# Give an equational proof $ \vdash (\exists x)(A \lor B) \equiv (\exists x)A \lor (\exists x)B $

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Give an equational proof** $$ \vdash (\exists x)(A \lor B) \equiv (\exists x)A \lor (\exists x)B $$

---

**What I tried**

> $(\exists x)(A \lor B)$

Applying *Definition of $\exists$*

> $\lnot (\forall x)\lnot (A \lor B)$

Applying *De morgan*

> $\lnot (\forall x) (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$

Applying *Distributivity of $\forall$ over $\land$*

> $\lnot (\forall x) \lnot A \land \lnot(\forall x) \lnot B$

Applying *Definition of $\exists$*

> $(\exists x)A \land (\exists x)B$

What can I do next ?

See George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008) or this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751922/give-an-equational-proof-vdash-forall-xa-rightarrow-b-equiv-exists) for a list of axioms and theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ∀-distributivity over ∧ step is wrong. Negation doesn't apply to (∀x) because (∀x) is not a sentence, so you can't just push ¬(∀x) in. Here is one way of proceeding.

$$¬(∀x)(¬A ∧ ¬B)$$

$$¬((∀x)¬A ∧ (∀x)¬B)$$

$$¬(¬(\exists x)A ∧ ¬(\exists x)B)$$

$$(\exists x)A \lor (\exists x)B$$