# True or False: $\exists x(P(x)\lor Q(x))\equiv \exists xP(x)\lor \exists yQ(y)$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

> True or False: $\exists x(P(x)\lor Q(x))\equiv \exists xP(x)\lor \exists yQ(y)$

My intuition tells me yes, these two things are equivalent. Assume the first, take some $x_0$ s.t. $P(x)\lor Q(x)$, do a proof by cases that the second is true as well. And similarly the other way.

But the proof seems really fast, and kind of trivial. Maybe that's just because the question itself is trivial, or maybe my intuition is incorrect!

First, are those two statements indeed equivalent? Secondly, is my idea for the proof headed in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: looks OK.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755373/give-an-equational-proof-vdash-exists-xa-lor-b-equiv-exists-xa-lor?rq=1 is related

Comment: You changed the statement.

Comment: Yes, I messed up the question. It reads as I intended now.

Comment: This is one of those statements where a proof isn't to establish the correctness of the statement, it is to establish the correctness of the proof theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`True.`
Assume $\exists x(P(x)\lor Q(x)).$ If $P(x)$ then $\exists xP(x)$, so $\exists xP(x)\lor \exists yQ(y)$. If $Q(x)$, then for $y=x$  we have $Q(y).$ So $\exists xP(x)\lor \exists yQ(y)$.

Assume  $\exists xP(x)\lor \exists yQ(y)$. If $\exists xP(x)$, then for this $x$, we have $P(x)\lor Q(x)$, done. Similarly for $\exists yQ(y)$.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of the result by cases using a proof checker:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Thank you for cheerleader for openlogicproject.org.  I spent a good deal of the weekend going through all of their exercises for fun and it was a great mental workout!

Comment: @MatthewDaly It is a great proof checker.