# Give a Hilbert-style proof $ \vdash ( x=y \rightarrow y = x) $

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Give a Hilbert-style proof** $$ \vdash ( x=y \rightarrow y = x) $$

---

I don't know where to start. I thought maybe I can use **Ax5** *(Identity axiom)* $ x = x $ as a starting point.

See George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008) or this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751922/give-an-equational-proof-vdash-forall-xa-rightarrow-b-equiv-exists) for a list of axioms and theorems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can "rewrite" Amr's proof with Tourlakis' rules as follows.

Start from **Ax6** [page 139] : this group contains all formulae of the form :

> > $\vdash t = s \rightarrow (A[x := t] \equiv A[x :=s])$.

It is called the "Leibniz axiom (group) for equality".

Using the following instance of **Ax6**, with $A(x) := (w = x)$ :

> $\vdash x = y \rightarrow ((w = x)[w := x] \equiv (w = x)[w := y])$

we get :

> $\vdash x = y \rightarrow ((x = x) \equiv (y = x))$.

Now, as per Amr's answer, assume :

$x = y$;

by *modus ponens* we get :

$x = y \vdash ((x = x) \equiv (y = x))$.

But we have **Ax5** : $\vdash x = x$; using **Equanimity** [page 39] we have :

$x = y \vdash y = x$.

A last step with *Deduction Theorem* and we will have :

> > $\vdash (x = y \rightarrow y = x).$

Comment: In the first step, How can $( x=x)[x:=y]$ gives us $(y=x)$ ? It should be $(y=y)$.

Comment: @Tennisman - you are right : my mistake. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't which proof system you are using.

$x=y\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$   (Given)

Assume $ \lnot(y=x)\,\,\,\,\,\,\, $

Therefore $\lnot(y=y)$ (Let $P(x,y)$ be $\lnot(x=y)$, since we know $x=y$ as a given. We can use Leibniz rule to deduce $P(y,y)$ by substituting $y$ for $x$ to get $\lnot(y=y)$)

$y=y$  (because this is axiom AX5 as you say in your question)

Contradiction

Therefore $\lnot \lnot(y=x)$

Thus, $y=x$

$\square$