# Give an equational proof $ \vdash (\forall x)(A \rightarrow (\exists x)B) \equiv ((\exists x)A \rightarrow (\exists x)B)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Give an equational proof** $$ \vdash (\forall x)(A \rightarrow (\exists x)B) \equiv ((\exists x)A \rightarrow (\exists x)B)$$

---

I don't know where to start. Maybe I could start with $ (\forall x)(A \rightarrow (\exists x)B) $ and change it to $ (\forall x)(\lnot A \lor (\exists x)B)$.

See George Tourlakis, *Mathematical Logic* (2008) or this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751922/give-an-equational-proof-vdash-forall-xa-rightarrow-b-equiv-exists) for a list of axioms and theorems.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am stuck. I can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have proposed, transform : $(∀x)(A \rightarrow (∃x)B)$ into :

> $(∀x)(\lnot A \lor (∃x)B)$.

Then, apply **6.4.2 Corollary** : $\vdash (\forall x)(A \lor B) \equiv A \lor (\forall x)B$, provided $x$ is not free in $A$,

where $x$ is not free in $(∃x)B$, to get :

$(∀x)\lnot A \lor (∃x)B$.

Then we "switch" to $\exists$ :

$\lnot(\exists x)A \lor (∃x)B$.

Finally, we reintroduce $\rightarrow$ :

> > $(\exists x)A \rightarrow (∃x)B$.

All steps are equivalences.