# prove this theorem $\vdash (\exists x_i (A\to B)\to (A\to \exists x_i B))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-systems

Here is my thought

> to prove the theorem we should get $\{\exists x_i (A \to B), A\} \vdash \exists x_i B $

then, I don't know how to process...

Comment: Informally, pick $x_i$ such thhat $A\to B$. Then using $A$ we conclude $B$. Hence for this $x_i$, we have $B$.

Comment: modus ponens...

Comment: What are your inference rules?

Comment: As in your previous post, you have to specify the *proof system* you are using; with *Natural Deduction* it is quite easy, following Hagen's hint.

Comment: you can use rules from this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751922/give-an-equational-proof-vdash-forall-xa-rightarrow-b-equiv-exists)@GitGud

Comment: Think of an example. Assume: "there is a number $x_i$ such that: if the moon is made of green cheese, then $x_i$ is an odd perfect number"  Deduce: "If the moon is made of green cheese, then there is an odd perfect number $x_i$".

Comment: I understand the sentence, but I just have a hard time to formally prove it

Comment: It is probably more useful for kengkeng to look at those rules and see which one applies, than to ask Git Gud to do it for him.

Comment: I would recommend using $A \rightarrow B \equiv \lnot A \lor B$ as well as $(\exists x ~ A \lor B) \equiv \bigg((\exists x ~ A) \lor (\exists x~B) \bigg)$

Comment: In the long answer to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323029/how-to-show-that-vdash-forall-x-beta-to-alpha-leftrightarrow-exists-x) you can find a proof with Enderton's axioms.

Comment: thank you all, I derived it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $\exists{x_i}(A\rightarrow{B})\equiv\neg \forall{x_i}\neg(A\rightarrow{B})\equiv\neg \forall{x_i}(A\land\neg{B})$ and the instantiate universal quantifier.