# How to prove by equational proof

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

⊢(∃x)A≡(∃z)A[x:=z] where z is fresh for A

rules same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751922/give-an-equational-proof-vdash-forall-xa-rightarrow-b-equiv-exists?fbclid=IwAR0lmp-0GvXBLGOU3DKVunKzymHsQorNrcUGc_CYNclJ4vLucMAOh_sNttc)

I proved via hilbert style to prove
⊢(∀x) A ≡ (∀z) A [x:=z] where z is fresh for A
but struggling with equational proof for
⊢(∃x)A≡(∃z)A[x:=z] where z is fresh for A

Comment: Maybe you have to use the fact/definition : $(∃x)A \equiv \lnot (∀x) \lnot A$.

Comment: using that definition, I will get ¬(∀x) ¬A ≡ ¬(∀z) ¬A [x:=z] ? How do you do this equational proof  to prove that?